# rep function strange error

Tags: r, rep

When I perform:

```
a <- seq(1,1.5,0.1)
b <- c(1,1.1,1.4,1.5)

x <- rep(c(a,b),times=c(2,1))
```

> Error in rep(c(a, b), c(2, 1)) : invalid 'times' argument

Why?

Comment: When you concatenate it is one vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we concatenate (`c`) two vectors, it becomes a single vector.  If the idea would be to replicate 'a' by 2 and 'b' by 1, we place them in a `list`, and use `rep`.  The output will be a `list`, which can be `unlist`ed to get a `vector`.

```
 unlist(rep(list(a,b), c(2,1)))
```

Comment: but when I do `rep(c(0,7),times=c(4,2))` it is working. So I confused.

Comment: @Alexander The length of 0,7 is two which matches the length of times.

Answer (score 1):

Marked answer is already perfect: Here an alternative using `mapply`

```
unlist(mapply(function(x,n)rep(x,n),list(a,b),c(2,1)))
```